Windows Terminal Preview の設定ファイルが存在するジャンクションフォルダを作成するとプレインストールされている Windows Terminal がエラーを起こす
  2024-05x64ベースシステム用累積更新プログラム(KB5037771)適用済み Windows11 において、 プレインストールされている "Windows Terminal" の settings.json は %LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState に保存されています。対して GitHub から zip をダウンロードし解凍した "Windows Terminal Preview v1.21.1272.0" の settings.json は %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows Terminal に保存されます。
  ここから本題です。 %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows Terminal が存在していてもあるいは削除してもプレインストールされている Windows Terminal に影響を与えませんが、
Move-Item -Path "${Env:LOCALAPPDATA}\Microsoft\Windows Terminal" -Destination "実体ファイルがあるディレクトリ"
New-Item -ItemType Junction -Path "${Env:LOCALAPPDATA}\Microsoft\Windows Terminal" -Value "実体ファイルがあるディレクトリ"

を実行してジャンクションフォルダを作成すると、プレインストールされている "Windows Terminal" が
ファイルから設定を読み込むことができませんでした。末尾のコンマを含めて構文エラーを確認してください。
{アプリケーション エラー}
例外 %s (0x

Windows ターミナルの既定の設定を一時的に使用しています。

というエラーを発生させます。別にジャンクションフォルダを作る必要もないのですが気になりました。理由あるいは原因をご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけますでしょうか。補足として、どの状況でも "Windows Terminal Preview v1.21.1272.0" はエラーを発生させず、"実体ファイルがあるディレクトリ" はZドライブに存在しています。

"実体ファイルがあるディレクトリ" がCドライブ以外にあるとエラーを起こすようです。ただそもそもなぜ "Windows Terminal Preview v1.21.1272.0" の設定ファイルの所在がプリインの "Windows Terminal" に影響を与えるのかは依然としてわかりません。

ファイルの格納場所は3種類あるようですね。こちらの説明ではプレビュー版の本来のパスは%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminalPreview_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.jsonで、質問に書かれた%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows Terminal\settings.jsonは非パッケージ版のための物のようですが。設定の JSON ファイル

依然として「zip版Windows Terminal Previewの設定ファイルに関するジャンクションフォルダの宛先がCドライブ以外の場合、プリインのWindows Terminalがエラーを起こす理由」はわかっていませんが、 Windowsターミナルポータブルモード によってsettings.jsonをzip版Windows Terminal Previewフォルダ配下のsettingsフォルダーに置くことは可能みたいです。
